# VueJs + Element UI : How to custom el-dialog title?

Tags: vuejs2, modal-dialog, element-ui

I created a dialog with a custom el-dialog title using the el-icon, but the el-icon does not appear.
how to make the icon appear ?

here my code

```
<el-dialog :title="titleData" :visible.sync="dialogVisible" width="30%">
  <span>This is a message</span>
  <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
    <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = false">Confirm</el-button>
  </span>
</el-dialog>

methods: {
  setTitle() {
  this.titleData = '<el-icon-info></el-icon-info>' + 'Info'
}
```

here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/y93kvew5/6/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use the slot `title` available on the `el-dialog` component. Here is your fiddle updated with a working solution : https://jsfiddle.net/budgw/y93kvew5/10/

Answer (score 1):

### Slot

—: content of Dialog

title: content of the Dialog title

footer: content of the Dialog footer

```
<el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible" width="30%">
  <span slot="title"><el-icon-info></el-icon-info>Info</span>
  <span>This is a message</span>
  <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
    <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = false">Confirm</el-button>
  </span>
</el-dialog>
```